# Regarding "have a say on this"

Tags: grammaticality

Is the following sentence grammatical, the context is when we want the boss to comment on something the team has decided:

> Does John have a say on this?

Comment: “a say *in* this” would be more usual in my dialect.

Comment: "on this" would be used with a topic under debate, "in this" with a decision or process.

Answer (score 0):

I would say it's *perhaps* slightly incorrect for the context, as you haven't actually stated that you want John to have a say, you've just asked if he does have a say.

Your phrasing might also be heard in a context where some plan is going to go ahead, but someone feels that John really ought to have a say before proceeding. In that context, it would be presented somewhat assertively as a challenge to whoever seems to be proceeding without John's say. It might also be asked neutrally, where someone is simply wondering if John is one of the people who will be asked/required to share his view on something.

For your context, I would say something like:

> Can we get John's take on this?
>
> We should get John's take on this.
>
> I'd like to get John's take on this.
>
> Etc.

With all that said, it would depend largely on context, and your phrasing might actually be fine. It would depend quite a lot on the preceding dialogue, who was present, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the sentence is perfectly fine. If you substitute "an opinion" for "a say" it might sound more typical.

> Does John have a say on this?
>
> Does John have an opinion on this?

If you use "get" instead of "have," I think it changes the meaning slightly.

> Does John get a say on this?

To me, this implies that either (1) the speaker doesn't think John is going to agree with the decision; or (2) the question is really whether John can override the decision (since he's the boss).